# Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the curves about $x=1$

Tags: calculus, volume

I have to find the volume of a solid bound by $y=x$, $y=0$, $x=2$, and $x=4$, rotated by $x=1$. I'm doing fine with these problems when the regions are "right next" to the line upon which they rotate, but when they're apart I get very confused. What am I missing here? Any help (with this particular problem and or in general) would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you all!

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the region in question is a trapezoid, the shell method may be a bit simpler to contend with, as we can cover the entire revolved region "all in one go".  The "slices" for this method are always *parallel* to the rotation axis, so the radii are "horizontal" and the "walls" of the shells are "vertical" here.  The "thickness" of the shells is $ \ dx \ $ , so we will be integrating in the $ x-$ direction.  The interval is then $ [ 2, 4 ] , $ the "radius arm" for a shell is $ \ r = (x-1) \ , $ and the "height" of each shell is $ \ h(x) = x - 0 = x \ . $  Here is a picture of the situation:

[image]

This is where a picture is valuable.  If the trapezoid were in contact with the $ y-$ axis, the "radius arm" would simply have a length $ \ x \ $ over to the $ \ x-$ coordinate of the slice we were integrating.  Since we are revolving the trapezoid around $ \ x = 1 \ , $ however, our reference is shifted *to the right* by one unit, so we must subtract 1 off of the length of the radius arm, making it $ \ r = x - 1 \ $ .  (If the rotation axis were $ \ x = -1 \ $ , the radius arm would be one unit *longer*, thus $ \ r = x + 1 \ .) $

The infinitesimal volume of a cylindrical shell is $ \ dV = 2 \pi \cdot r \cdot h \ $ d(radius) ,  so that will be $ \ dV = 2 \pi \cdot (x-1) \cdot x \ \ dx \ $ here.  The volume integral is then

$$ \int_2^4 \ \ 2 \pi \ (x-1) \ \cdot \ x \ \ dx \ . $$

By way of comparison, here are the two sets of "disk radii" **dmk** is describing for the disk method (a little more work to set up, but the integrals are still easy...).

[image]

Comment: Note that the washer method doesn't give you the nice vertical walls that the shell method does: You only get one "vertical" wall, $y = 0$, which is vertical if you look at it sideways :). That's why we can't make do with only one integral.

Comment: +1. Good explanation of how to use limits of integration for choosing a method, as well as matching all the parts of $dV$. As far as explaining the space in the middle goes, I think I still find the washer method a little more intuitive, but what *I* find more intuitive is, obviously, not the point here.

Comment: It's a shame we don't discuss Pappus' Centroid Theorems much in the current curriculum.  It is quite simple to locate the centroids and express the areas of the square and triangular regions, and from there, to apply the Second Theorem to get the volume of this solid of revolution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the washer method if you integrate with respect to $y$.

In cases where there isn't any kind of gap between the region and the axis of rotation, what we get is a solid, uh, *thing*.  (Hence, I guess, the phrase *solid of rotation*, which sounds better.) So if we wanted a cylinder of radius $r$, we could set up the integral

$$\int_a^b \pi r^2 dy$$

which would give us the volume of a cylinder $b - a$ units high.

Of course, you could fit another, smaller cylinder inside; let's say it has radius $s$. Its integral is in essence the same: $\int_a^b \pi s^2 dy$. But what if we wanted not a cylinder but, I don't know, the volume of a cored pineapple? If the pineapple itself has radius $r$ and hole down the middle of radius $s$, then just calculating the first integral overestimates its volume — by exactly the amount given by the second integral. Therefore, we subtract one from the other. We can then combine these integrals to get

$$\int_a^b \pi r^2 - \pi s^2 dy$$

The idea with your question is similar, only each radius is a bit smaller; because we have the axis of rotation at $x=1$, it's closer to the region. If there weren't anything taken out of the middle, we'd have something like a cylinder of radius $3$; however, there *is* something taken out of the middle, and it has radius $1$. It's a skinnier pineapple, and its core is similarly skinnier — but that means the distance between the core and the edge is the same.

Anyway, your question requires two integrals via the washer method, one for $y \in [0,2]$ and one for $y \in [2, 4]$. With the above in mind, we can set up the first part of the integral as:

$$\int_0^2 \pi (4 - 1)^2 - \pi (2 - 1)^2 dy$$

(Of course, this can be simplified a lot.) What's left over is the diagonal part, which is, admittedly, slightly trickier. What do you get for that?

Comment: The "shell method" would be less of a pain in the...

Comment: @RecklessReckoner, I was sorta assuming so, but it's been a while since I've used that :). I was looking at my notes so that I could update my answer with a second approach. (Beyond that, I was also wondering whether the idea of subtracting out an empty space would be as clear with the shell method; that seemed to be part of the OP's question.)

Comment: It didn't seem to be that dealing with a "washer" was the issue so much as just what the difference in set-up is when the rotation axis doesn't contact the region being revolved.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner, I didn't mean to suggest that the question *was* about the washer method. The OP asked about regions that are separated from their axis of rotation, and I answered in a way that (I hope) makes it a little more intuitive. True, there's only one integral to set up for the shell method (though I'm not sure the integral above is all that taxing). But I don't think the problem-solving skills the OP might employ in doing this problem the, uh, hard way would otherwise stay buried for the remainder of his or her second-semester calc class.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner, as for the shell method in particular, you would probably do a much better job explaining how that works than I would.

Comment: All right. I didn't want to just horn in...